# Terraform module with repeatable variable

Tags: terraform

Several resources, e.g. [aws_dynamodb_table](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html) have repeatable variables. In the case of the aws_dynamodb_table resource, `attribute` is repeatable which allows you to specify multiple attributes using either of the following syntax

```
attribute {
  name = "UserId"
  type = "S"
}

attribute {
  name = "GameTitle"
  type = "S"
}

attribute {
  name = "TopScore"
  type = "N"
}
```

or

```
attribute = [{
  name = "UserId"
  type = "S"
}, {
  name = "GameTitle"
  type = "S"
}, {
  name = "TopScore"
  type = "N"
}]
```

I like this interface and want to provide the same flexibility in my modules but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it. Is this possible for modules or is it only the built-in resources that can do this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you possibly show your module definition and explain what you'd like to change about it and how your current approach doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that either allows you to provide `attribute` multiple times as separate maps (which are then merged) or as a list.

You're going to want to take a look at the documentation related to [Input Variable Configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html)

In particular, you will want to look at the section titled `Variable Merging`.

I believe you could do something like this for similar behavior (from the docs above, give them a read :P)

```
foo {
   quux="bar"
} 
foo {
   bar="baz"
}
```

This would mean `foo` returns:

```
{
  quux = "bar"
  bar = "baz"
}
```

Hope that helps!